# Full list of verbs

Tags: verbs, lists, irregular

Is there any conjugated full list of verbs in English available? I've found lists of the most common ones but I'd like to have a full list that takes into account all the irregular ones as well.

Comment: English has, by some counts, a million words. If only 1/3rd of those were verbs you’d still be looking at more than 330,000 verbs and their full list of conjugations. I think that’s not what you’re looking for. Let’s back up a step. What’s your motivation here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for resources

Comment: Lists of irregular verbs are available and seem far more sensible (there being so few in comparison).

Comment: I'm building a software that needs to recognize the verbs in a piece of text. That's why the list should be more or less comprehensive, otherwise it wouldn't capture a large percentage of words that are actually verbs.

Comment: @woodgate Ah, I think this is the wrong way around. You have to determine a word’s function by its role in the sentence, not use (one of) its function to determine its role. You’ll get an enormous number of false positives and false negatives this way. The word *run* is a verb, a noun, an adjective, and adverb, etc at various times and various contexts. Other times what you think is a noun will be used as a verb: people verb nouns all the time. Similarly nouns can be used attributively as adjectives and adverbs. You have to go the other way with your syntactic analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this list is very complete with most of the most common verbs but also irregular forms.
https://www.wordexample.com/list/verbs-in-english